# How to add new Button to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid x:Name="myMainGrid">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Append:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button newBtn = new Button();
    myMainGrid.Children.Add(newBtn);
}
```

Problem: In function "button_Click" the whole WPF turns grey. No creation of the button happened no append happend. Even the static Button dissapeared.

My aim: Changing the "look" of the WPF by creating a new Button. I know it would not change I lot but I want try new Things.

I am a new beginner and I don't understand what happened... Should I Create a new Grid? Where is the bug?

Comment: Edit: Found my bug. I have not entered width and height. :D

Comment: You may not have found the bug you *think* you did, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your new button has no properties set and was put into a `Grid`. This means that it will *fill* the entire area given to it (in this case, your whole window). Because it will be the last child it will have the highest z-index and appear over your original button.

So basically, **your whole window was filled with your new button**.

To fix it, just set the `Width`, `Height` and `Margin` properties on your new button so it can appear where you want (and at the right size). Alternatively, just use a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid`, as it will arrange the buttons next to each other for you and force the button to be the smallest possible size (given the lack of content, it might be invisible due to 0 height, just add some text if so).

As a pretty important side-note, you shouldn't manipulate the visual tree this way in WPF. You will almost always have a data collection that you are binding against, letting the framework create these controls for you.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that I have done in the past when dynamically adding controls to a Grid was to use the Grid.SetRow() and Grid.SetColumn() methods. These basically take your control and an int as a parameter and sets that control to the specified row/column. For instance I use this to add multiple canvas controls (195 of them) to the grid then set each one in a specific order.

```
int row = 2; 
int column = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 195; i++)
{
     Canvas c = new Canvas();

     gridMain.Children.Add(c);

     Grid.SetRow(c, row);
     Grid.SetColumn(c, column);  

     if (column == 14)
     {
         column = 0;
         row++;
     }
     else
     {
         column++;
     }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that if you dont specify which columns/rows you want to add your controls to, it will just keep adding them to the first cell in the grid!

Comment: I would strongly recommend going with an `ItemsControl` here; you can use attached properties to set Grid.Column/Row. This is just painful. Also, the OP had no rows/columns set up